# Skip pressing CTRL+C in Timeout Command

Tags: windows, batch-file

If I use `timeout sec /nobreak`, it still can be skipped by pressing Ctrl+C, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent the user from stopping it with CTRL-C, but you can suppress the prompt with 'nul,' example:

timeout -t 10 -nobreak > nul

I found that, for almost all users, this will stop them from trying to press a key.

Comment: Is it possible to set a specific key to skip the timeout, or all my options is "any-key" or "no-key" ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, timeout command sets `%errorlevel%` to 1 if CTRL+C is pressed.

So you can try this:

```
@echo off
:settime
timeout 5 /nobreak
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto settime
echo/Yes! CTRL+C were not pressed!
pause
```

Comment: This not works. When the `Ctrl-C` is pressed the Batch file itself is cancelled and cmd.exe ask for confirmation of this...

Comment: Yes, but if you type `N` the batch file won't be cancelled.

Comment: exactly I want to skip that question which asks for Y/N, and it is not happening with your code :(

Comment: @Stranger: you can't do that, the user always has the option to cancel the batch file execution.  Sounds like you should be using a scripting language (such as vbscript or powershell) rather than a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start /b` with timeout.

```
start "title" /b cmd /c "timeout 5 /nobreak"
```

This can't be canceled, as the timeout runs in the same window but in a different cmd.exe instance.